NodeJS http.createServer keepAlive
I am using NodeJS 18 LTS and one of the options to pass to http.createServer is the keepAlive boolean. Default this value is false [1].
My assumption is that when the server is created with keepAlive set to false that the server does not support keep alive on the sockets.
However, I have noticed that when creating the server with keepAlive set to false, when a client makes a request with the header connection: keep-alive that my server still still responds with connection: keep-alive and keep-alive: timeout=5.
My understanding is that the client "can" request to keep the connection alive but if the server is not capable of doing this (i.e. keepAlive set to false when the server was created) that the server should respond with connection: close.
Why is my server responding with connection: keep-alive when the server was created with keepAlive set to false?
[1] https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener
